# Can't remove / find git hook

Tags: linux, git, githooks

Once upon a time I installed some git hooks a la these instructions:

> Clone this directory, then run `git config --global init.templatedir $template_dir`. Afterward new repositories will use this directory for templates.

Now I want to remove these hooks. I've unset the template in my `.gitconfig`, I've deleted the `.git-templates` folder, but no matter what the hooks still run.

> File ".git/hooks/pre-commits/security-scan", line 49, in check_code_diff
>       code = code.decode()
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 113: ordinal not in range(128)

But I can't seem to find this file *anywhere* on my machine! Only the sample hooks are in my repository's hooks folder

```
applypatch-msg.sample       pre-push.sample
commit-msg.sample           pre-rebase.sample
post-update.sample          prepare-commit-msg.sample
pre-applypatch.sample       update.sample
pre-commit.sample
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message you get, it seems the name of the hook script is `security-scan`. You should be able find this file by searching through the entire filesystem:

```
find / -name security-scan 2>/dev/null
```

I muted `stderr` to reduce noise. Also, we know for a fact that the file is readable by your user, if it wasn't, it wouldn't be causing issues.

You could remove these files by adding `-delete` flag.
You might want to remove the entire directories too,
for that you can use this:

```
find / -name security-scan -exec sh -c 'rm -fr "$(dirname "{}")"' \; 2>/dev/null
```